# Namespace being added to XML

Tags: c#, xml, webrequest

I have a WebRequest service (External Client) that sends

```
<Sales>
   <Customer>
        <Name>John</Name>
   </Customer>
   <Goods>
       <Good>
          <id>5445</id>
       </Good>
       <Good>
          <id>6767</id>
       </Good>
    </Goods>
 </Sales>
```

But when XML is received, the Goods mysteriously has a namespace added to it.

```
<Good xlmns="http://example.com/INT">
```

My Service is :-

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SendRequest", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public Sales(clsCustomer Customer, clsGoods Goods)
```

I have to remove the Xlmns.

When the XML is parsed into the parameters of the function, the Customer object is filled however the Goods object is null.  When I add an extra node layer between Goods and Good and use XMLElement to accept the values, I find the node Good now has a namespace which I didn't add.  Internally, Good is now `<Good xlmns="http://example/Int">`, how do I prevent .NET adding xmlns ?

Comment: do you mean that when you read the bytes from the socket you get an xmlns added? or do you mean that it is added when you parse it as xml? or do you mean that when you create the xml it is added? or do you mean that when you save the xml after you have parsed it that it is added? Can you add a short example which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: You need to find out where that namespace is coming from and understand why it's being added. You shouldn't just remove something just because you don't understand it, namespace declarations are very important in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `Goods` to a list of strings from the list of integers first:

```
Goodstr = Goods.ConvertAll(delegate(int i) { return i.ToString(); });
```

and use that to populate the XML